How can i make a C program exit when key Q is pressed?
i am making a counting program, and i want to add a feature that quits the program, but i don't really know how to do it. i have seen examples on how to do it, but all of them are for windows. please help
os is linux debian
i tried adding "i = getchar();" and then added an if: "if (i==1){break;}" but nothing happened. i was expecting it to get a value of 1 and then exit.
code:
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <threads.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main() {
    start:
    struct timespec duration;
    struct timespec remaining; 
    int time, num;  

    duration.tv_sec = 1;    
    duration.tv_nsec = 0;   

    time = 0;
    num = 0;
    
    while(time <= 32767)
    {
      int result = nanosleep(&duration, &remaining);
      num++; //adds 1 to the number
      if (result == 0) 
      {
          printf("Seconds Passed: ");
          printf("%d\n", num); //prints the number
          time++; //adds 1 to the time
      }
      else if (result == -1)
      {
         printf("Error with nanosleep\n");
         goto start;
      }
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}


if (i==1)... Why would that be true if the Q key is entered and getchar() returns 'Q' (or 'q')?

Or is the problem that getchar() blocks until there's some actual input to read? Then since you're on Linux there are multiple ways to handle it, but one of the easier is the ncurses library.

getch() is best, imo.  ie:  int key = getch();  if(key == 'q' || key == 'Q') ...  Here is a nice page on coding a getch() for Linux.

An alternate approach might be to set a handler for the INTR signal that sets a flag which your main loop checks for, cleans up, and exits. It's not the "q" key, but it is a single keystroke and still allows your program to gracefully exit.

Related: How can I prevent scanf() to wait forever for an input character?

You want to do two things at the same time:

run a loop with sleep printing seconds
wait for q

There are generally two popular ways to implement multitasking:

multithreading/multiprocessing
event loop

Multithreading using standard C11 threads might look like the following:
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <threads.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int printer(void *arg) {
  // prints seconds until shoudlexit is set
  atomic_bool *shouldexit = arg;
  for (unsigned time = 0; time <= 32767; time++) {
    printf("Seconds Passed: %d\n", time);
    sleep(1);
    if (atomic_load(shouldexit)) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

void sigusr1_handler(int ignore) {}

int main() {
  atomic_bool shouldexit = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false);
  thrd_t thr;
  thrd_create(&thr, printer, &shouldexit);
  // wait for q or end of stream
  for (int c; (c = getchar()) != EOF;) {
    if (c == 'q') {
      break;
    }
  }
  printf("Exiting...\n");
  atomic_store(&shouldexit, true);
  // send yourself a signal to break sleep mid sleep.
  signal(SIGUSR1, sigusr1_handler);
  raise(SIGUSR1);
  thrd_join(thr, 0);
}

While an event loop might look like this:
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
  struct pollfd fds[] = {{.fd = STDIN_FILENO, .events = POLLIN}};
  int time = 0;
  while (1) {
    int r = poll(fds, sizeof(fds) / sizeof(*fds), 1000);
    if (r == 0) {
      printf("Seconds Passed: %d\n", time);
      time++;
    } else {
      int c = getchar();
      if (c == EOF || c == 'q') {
        printf("Exiting...\n");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

You might be interested in: man pthread_create man poll man signal man 7 signal man sleep man pipe https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread .
You might also be interested in How do you do non-blocking console I/O on Linux in C? to read q without having to press enter.
The way you used goto in your code smells for me. Do not use goto (that way). You might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto#Criticism . The kernel coding style https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/process/coding-style.html#centralized-exiting-of-functions shows the only acceptable way to use goto. In the case of your presented code, you could have just used a normal loop.

I think this is not what the OP asked for. Their main issue is that the program simply does not see any input after a regular (i.e., non-enter, non-break etc.) key press since the terminal is in line mode.

Here's another approach.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
  int flags = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
  fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

  while (1) {
    // Do some work here
    printf("Doing some work...\n");
    sleep(1);  // Simulate work

    // Check for input
    char c;
    ssize_t result = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);

    if (result > 0) {
      printf("Received input: %c", c);
    } else if (result == -1 && errno != EAGAIN) {
      perror("read");
      exit(1);
    }
    // If result is -1 and errno is EAGAIN, it means no data was available
  }

  return 0;
}

This uses the underlying file descriptor for standard in and sets it to non-blocking. This prevents the read from waiting for input.
Note that this uses Unix-style calls (read(), fcntl()), which are POSIX compliant, but not standard C library. Thus, this might not work as-is on non-Unix-like OSes (e.g. Windows).
Also, this solution (as with KamilCuk's solution) requires you to press return for your "q" to be read. If you want single-keystroke recognition, then you need to put the terminal driver into a special mode. I advise against doing that, partly due to the added complexity. Also, if your program exits prematurely without cleaning up, it will leave the terminal driver in the special mode, which you will not find usable. (There are things you can to do protect against even that, but it adds even more complexity.)
One more thing. KamilCuk's solution reacts immediately to the keystroke. Mine waits till the loop gets to the read(). This might be an advantage or a disadvantage, depending on your needs.
So three solutions. The right one depends on the details of your overall design. Mine is arguably the less complex, but also the least flexible, depending on what else is going on in your program.

Typical terminals send the input even in standard mode when enter is pressed; none of this should be necessary unless you are behind a pipe.

The title question is: "How can i make a C program exit when key Q is pressed?" Pressing 'Q' then 'Enter' does not give what the user asked for. Our hope is that this is "good enough", but we don't really know the requirements of the the OP's real program.
